# fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Could not find or access /home/jenkins/workspace/NonProd.json on the Ansible Controller

Tags: jenkins, ansible, ansible-template

I am trying to copy a JSON file using Ansible template to localhost and run a cURL command to import Datadog dasboard.

Jenkins error:

```
TASK [datadog-dashboard : Import Datadog Dashboard in main] ********************
16:54:24  included: /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/5052/non_production/monitoring-as-code/src/roles/datadog-dashboard/tasks/Import.yaml for localhost
16:54:24  
16:54:24  TASK [datadog-dashboard : Copying Dashboard json file] *************************
16:54:24  fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Could not find or access 'src/roles/datadog-dashboard/templates/datadog-dashboard/non_production/NonProd.json'\nSearched in:\n\t/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/5052/non_production/monitoring-as-code/src/roles/datadog-dashboard/templates/src/roles/datadog-dashboard/templates/datadog-dashboard/non_production/NonProd.json\n\t/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/5052/non_production/monitoring-as-code/src/roles/datadog-dashboard/src/roles/datadog-dashboard/templates/datadog-dashboard/non_production/NonProd.json\n\t/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/5052/non_production/monitoring-as-code/src/roles/datadog-dashboard/tasks/templates/src/roles/datadog-dashboard/templates/datadog-dashboard/non_production/NonProd.json\n\t/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/5052/non_production/monitoring-as-code/src/roles/datadog-dashboard/tasks/src/roles/datadog-dashboard/templates/datadog-dashboard/non_production/NonProd.json\n\t/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/5052/non_production/monitoring-as-code/src/templates/src/roles/datadog-dashboard/templates/datadog-dashboard/non_production/NonProd.json\n\t/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/5052/non_production/monitoring-as-code/src/src/roles/datadog-dashboard/templates/datadog-dashboard/non_production/NonProd.json on the Ansible Controller.\nIf you are using a module and expect the file to exist on the remote, see the remote_src option"}
```

Ansible code:

```
- name: Copying Dashboard json file
  template:
    src: src/roles/datadog-dashboard/templates/datadog-dashboard/{{ application_env }}/NonProd.json
    dest: /tmp/5052-dash.json
    mode: '0644'
```

Comment: copy or template? And the file cannot be found. Adjust the `src` value w a correct path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for following path only:

```
 templates/datadog-dashboard/{{ application_env }}/NonProd.json
```